# Extra bracket in json marshaling

Tags: json, go

I want to combine a series of small json files into a single one (vscode snippet). Small files content looks like:

```
"baz": {
    "foo": "a",
    "bar": "b"
}
```

and final file **should** looks like:

```
{
     "baz": {
         "foo": "a",
         "bar": "b"
     },
     "baz2": {
         "foo": ["a", "b"],
         "bar": "c"
     },
     ...
}
```

but I get extra brackets over each `baz`:

```
{
     "baz": [{
         "foo": "a",
         "bar": "b"
     }],
     "baz2": [{
         "foo": ["a", "b"],
         "bar": "c"
     }],
     ...
}
```

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

const root = "rootFolder"
const tabSpace = "  "

type Snippet struct {
    Prefix      interface{} `json:"prefix"`
    Body        string      `json:"body"`
    Description string      `json:"description"`
}

func main() {
    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    snippetFile := filepath.Join(cwd, "snippets", "sampleSnippet.json")
    snippetFile = filepath.FromSlash(snippetFile)

    os.Chdir(root)
    folders := getFolders(".")
    snippets := map[string][]Snippet{}

    for _, folder := range folders {
        files := getFiles(folder)
        for _, file := range files {
            os.Chdir(folder)
            snippetName := folder + "." + strings.TrimSuffix(file, ".json")
            jsonFileBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
            var snippet Snippet
            json.Unmarshal(jsonFileBytes, &snippet)
            namedSnippet := map[string]Snippet{
                snippetName: snippet,
            }
            for k, v := range namedSnippet {
                snippets[k] = append(snippets[k], v)
            }
            os.Chdir("..")
        }
    }
    output, _ := json.MarshalIndent(snippets, "", "  ")
    _ = ioutil.WriteFile(snippetFile, output, 0755)
}

func getFolders(root string) []string {
    var folders []string
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(root)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, fileInfo := range files {
        if fileInfo.IsDir() {
            folders = append(folders, fileInfo.Name())
        }
    }
    return folders
}

func getFiles(dir string) []string {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var result []string
    for _, file := range files {
        result = append(result, file.Name())
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your attempt/code this time :) What if two different "small" files have the top-level key "baz"? How do you combine them together then? Do you need to create a single "baz" key with an array of entries, or is it an error? I think you need to answer this design question first. Assuming you want to see all these entries together, keeping them in an array is reasonable so the "extra brackets" make sense, no?

Comment: @EliBendersky: Uniqueness in small file keys is guaranteed. Extra brackets breaks `vscode` snippet api.

Comment: If uniqueness is guaranteed, you don't need to `append` anything. Your snippets should be as @colm.anseo's answer suggests, and just assign `snippets[k] = namedSnippet`. You only need the `append` if you're collecting a slice of `Snippet` for each possible name. If names are unique across all files, you don't need the slice and you don't need the append. The bracket is there because each entry is a slice; no slice - no bracket.

Comment: @EliBendersky: with `snippets := map[string]Snippet{}` and `snippets[k] = namedSnippet`I get error: `cannot use namedSnippet (variable of type map[string]Snippet) as Snippet value in assignment`

Comment: @EliBendersky: `snippets[k] = v` did the trick. thanks.

Comment: You don't need that loop at all, and you don't need the namedSnippet map. I think just doing `snippets[snippetName] = snippet` will suffice, right after the `Unmarshal` line.

Answer (score 1):

You have a slice of `[]Snippet` - you just want a single `Snippet`

Change:

```
snippets := map[string][]Snippet{}
```

To:

```
snippets := map[string]Snippet{}
```

Comment: I have tried that. Then I get error on k, v loop that `invalid argument: snippets[k] (map index expression of type Snippet) is not a slicecompiler` (invalid append)

Comment: You need to track the map keys. A new key gets a new entry. A recycled key, the use `append` to add any new values to this "merged" item.

Comment: How to do that. A range provides new keys.